# Array index out of range when filling a Dictionary using text.Split

Tags: c#, arrays, dictionary, split

Basically I'm trying to fill a Dictionary using a TextAsset, but in the process I keep getting an "IndexOutOfRangeException: Array index is out of range." from one of the arrays and I'm not sure why... I'm using Visual studio Community in Unity 5, also, I've only started learning programming like 4 months ago and honestly have no clue what might be the problem...

```
public Dictionary<string, string> Items = new Dictionary<string, string>();

Start(){
var itemList = Resources.Load("ItemList", typeof(TextAsset)) as TextAsset;

        //populating the Dictionaries using previous text assets. Line by Line. 
        //Populating Dictionary with Text Asset with format Item:Id. The ':' symbol separates lines into columns
        string[] rows = itemList.text.Split('\n');
        foreach (string row in rows)
        {
            string[] data = row.Split(':');
            Items.Add(data[0].Trim(), data[1].Trim()); //exception is thrown in this line
        }
}
```

ItemList.txt has these test lines:

```
Health Potion:1
Mana potion:2
Beet:3
Poisonous Beet:4
Cheese Slice:5
```

Another thing is, Visual studio keeps underlining itemList (TextAsset) with a squiggly line in the text.Split line and showing the tooltip: Possible System.NullReferenceException. But unity doesn't show any errors regarding null References at all.

Anyway, any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Put a breakpoint at the line throwing the exception in the debugger and run your app. I bet `data` has less than 2 elements. That is because at least one `row` does not contain a `:`. Look at the contents of `itemList` in your debugger.

Comment: Hey thanks! I can't believe it was that simple, it was because there was an empty line at the end! But, anyway, Is there a way to go around that issue? To make the code ignore empty lines? guess, I'll have to take a look in the forums, or I'm going to get scolded for "piggyback" questions. Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
public Dictionary<string, int> Items = new Dictionary<string, int>();
...
string[] rows = itemList.text.Split('\n');
foreach (string row in rows)
{
    string[] data = row.Split(':');
    int i;
    if (data.Length > 1 && int.TryParse(data[1].Trim(), out i))
        Items.Add(data[0].Trim(), i);
}
```

Comment: Great, I'll use both suggestions, then!

Comment: Oh, there's just one thing, though, the numbers next to the item names are not fully representative of what the real numbers are going to be... The real numbers are going to be Id numbers pointing to some global variables made in a third party asset (Unity Asset Adventure creator), so they're unlikely to be in order. How would I adapt the code for that? I haven't tried it yet but it gives me the impression the code is meant to put the words in order of appearance (which is my mistake for not mention this before).

Comment: The numbers do not need to be in order for this code to work. However when you say “Id numbers” I suspect `Items` should be `new Dictionary<int, string>()` and you should use `Items.Add(i, data[0].Trim())`.

Comment: Also, “Items” is a vague and misleading name. If these things are a “third party asset” then `Assets` would be a better name.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that, I'll try it later. The problem wit the dictionary is I'm merging two dictionaries later,one has the items and ids, the another has a list of names (<string, string>). My intention is to verify a goal/circumstance (item use, specific action, or arrival to a location). If the requirement is fulfilled, reward the player (item or money) and switch to other goal, but I need a master list to verify what to assign (and avoid same goal twice in a row). For item rewards, I planned to use parsing to convert a dic.value into int. Anyway, that's why the dict is <string,string>.

Comment: To clarify, the Items dictionary holds item names and gVar Ids, the other dictionary holds the names of locations or actions which are also considered goals but don't have or need ids. I've used dictionaries because I wanted to use dict.ContainsKey for searching the list of goals (which will probably become pretty large...

Comment: Merging two dictionaries of different types does not sound like a good idea to me, but you have not explained what you are trying to accomplish in enough detail for me to make a recommendation.

Comment: I know, that's why I decided to leave all the dictionaries as <string, string>, Adventure creator only needs an Id number as a reference to give or remove items from an inventory. The name of the item is for me to actually compare against a list of Active Goals. The item itself isn't an asset file. That's why I was planing to just convert the Id string into an int whenever I need to add or remove inventory items.

Comment: Widening data types (e.g. storing ints as strings) is usually a mistake, especially if you later have to narrow it again. I suspect you should not be comparing the name of an item against a goal but, again, you have not given enough information to make a suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

There might be extra empty elements in your data, so when you call `Split` use the overload that takes a second argument:

```
string[] rows = itemList.text.Split('\n', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

This will remove any empty rows in your data

```
string[] data = row.Split(':', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

This will remove any cases where there's nothing before or after the colon.

You should also check that the resultant `data` array has a length of 2 before trying to address the elements:

```
if (data.Length == 2)
{
    Items.Add(data[0].Trim(), data[1].Trim());
}
else
{
    // Deal with the error - could be as simple as ignoring it or logging the dodgy data
}
```

Then the data will be what you expect it to be.

Comment: Note this still throws `NullReferenceException` if a row is nonempty but contains no ':'.

Comment: @DourHighArch true.